# how to put a switch in a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, switch-statement

I'm making a little mini game and I have to put multiple switches inside of themselves, so I really need to know how to put a switch into a few words so I can make this game. I have tried it so that it's fully written out but it takes FOREVER and it is very confusing as to what is what. please help!

**EDIT**: im sorry i made this so confusing... let me say that again in english (: what i need to do is make it so when they either choose one of the cases or if they choose none of them (default) it would reactivate the switch. the way the person would choose is through a prompt. so what i thought i could do was make a switch into a variable then use that variable inside the switch basicly creating an endless thing that if they choose default it asks them again. here is an example i will post it in one minute

here you go!:

```
    //this is the variable holding the switch
    /*I I I I I*/
    /*V V V V V*/

    var switch1 = {
    var choice = prompt("do you choose EXAMPLE or EXAMPLE").toUpperCase()
    switch(choice) {
        case 'EXAMPLE':
            //this will repeat the whole prompt
            switch1
        break;
        default:
            //this will repeat it too
            switch1
        break; }
    }
```

So how would i do this and make java accept this @ajaysinghdav10d?

Comment: please see the updated answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript allows you to nest switch statements.

Have a look at this dummy example in which a service returns the location of the customer and his choice of product. Based on the combination of Choice and Location, a function to return the co-ordinates of the nearest store is called; I have used dummy values where ever necessary and alerts to explain the flow of control within the nested switch statements:

```
var choice = "CHO2"; /* call getChoice() function returning values from {CHO1, CHO2, ...}*/
var location = "LOC1"; /*call getLocality() function returning values from {LOC1, LOC2, ...}*/
switch (location) {
    case "LOC1":
        switch (choice) {
            case "CHO1":
                /* redirectToCHO1ofLOC1() is a function returning co-ordinates of the store*/
                alert("redirectToCHO1ofLOC1");
                break;
            case "CHO2":
                alert("redirectToCHO2ofLOC1");
                break;
            default:
                alert("redirectToRegret");
                break;
        }
        break;
    case "LOC2":
        switch (choice) {
            case "CHO1":
                /* redirectToCHO1ofLOC2() is a function returning co-ordinates of the store*/
                alert("redirectToCHO1ofLOC2");
                break;
            case "CHO2":
                alert("redirectToCHO1ofLOC2");
                redirectToCHO2ofLOC2();
                break;
            default:
                alert("redirectToRegret");
                break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        alert("redirectToRegret");
        break;

}
```

**Updated answer based on the new context :**
You must use recursion for that matter. Put your switch inside a function and call that function from the case statement of your switch, please have a look at this:

```
function recursiveSwitch() {
    var choice = prompt("do you choose EXAMPLE or EXAMPLE").toUpperCase()
    switch (choice) {
        case 'EXAMPLE':
            //this will repeat the whole prompt
            recursiveSwitch();
            break;
        default:
            //this will repeat it too
            recursiveSwitch();
            break;
    }
}
```

Now just call the recursiveSwitch function from where ever you want and an endless loop would start.

Comment: Thanks a ton! also another method i found (which i hit myself in the face for not remembering) is simply using a while loop.... i also posted another question on a problem i had combining a switch Math.random and an if / else if statement lol help would be much appreciated